# AngularJS: How do I update my data model from my geocoding function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

AngularJS and JavaScript newbie, here.

I'm trying to build a controller that will submit a geocode request and update its model with the result. I'm having trouble updating the model, however.

You can see the example live in a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3aszL/

In my `submitQuery` function, I'm not able to properly pass the result of the geocode method back to the `search` array. Any pointers?

Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="weather">
    <div ng-controller="SearchController as searchCtrl" class="container-fluid">
        <div>
            <form ng-submit="searchCtrl.submitQuery()" name="searchForm" role="form" class="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="searchInput">Search</label>
                    <input id="searchInput" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="searchCtrl.search.geoQuery" placeholder="Enter your zip code...">
                    <input id="searchSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                </div>
            </form>

            <h1>{{ searchCtrl.search.resultLatLng }}</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="playback">
            <small>searchCtrl.query = {{ searchCtrl.search.geoQuery }}</small>
            <small>searchCtrl.resultLatLng = {{ searchCtrl.search.resultLatLng }}</small>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and my JS:

```
var app = angular.module("weather", []);

app.controller("SearchController", function($scope){
    var geocoder  = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    this.search = [
        {
            geoQuery: "",
            resultLatLng: "",
            resultCity: ""
        }
    ];

    this.submitQuery = function() {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': this.search.geoQuery}, function(result, status){
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                search.resultLatLng = {
                    lat: result[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    lng: result[0].geometry.location.lng()
                };
            } else {
                alert("Something went wrong: " + status);
                return false;
            }
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Maybe this Demo might help you: http://plnkr.co/edit/eGG9Kj?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your fiddle with a working solution that includes a couple corrections.
http://jsfiddle.net/3aszL/3/

The main issues:

1. Your `this.search` was an object inside an array.  It should just be a plain object (no array).
2. You can't use the keyword `this` inside another function call or a callback, as it will refer to something else.  I fixed it with the convention of adding `that = this` then using `that`.  Obviously, `this` is a confusing concept in javascript, but an important one.  Read up on `this` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.
3. This is another tricky one, but you sometime need to run `$scope.$apply()` in angular to get the view to update, especially if the operation is running in a callback of an asynchronous operation as we see here.  Here's a dated, but good read: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Good luck!

Comment: Excellent answer, ramdog. Thank you for the pointers and reading materials!